# Can't mark current page in jsp pagination

Tags: html, jsp, pagination

Here is my code:

```
   <ul class = "pagination">
            <%--For displaying Previous link except for the 1st page --%>
            <c:if test="${model.currentPage != 0}">
                <li><a href="getEmployeesByPage?page=${model.currentPage - 1}">Previous</a></li>
            </c:if>

            <%--For displaying Page numbers.
            The when condition does not display a link for the current page--%>

                <c:forEach begin="0" end="${model.noOfPages}" var="i">
                    <c:if test="${model.noOfPages != 0}">
                        <c:choose>
                        <c:when test="${model.currentPage eq i}">
                            <li><b>${i+1}</b></li>
                        </c:when>
                        <c:otherwise>
                     <li><a href="getEmployeesByPage?page=${i}">${i+1}</a></li>
                        </c:otherwise>
                        </c:choose>
                    </c:if>
                 </c:forEach>


 <%--For displaying Next link --%>
            <c:if test="${model.currentPage lt model.noOfPages}">
                <li><a href="getEmployeesByPage?page=${model.currentPage + 1}">Next</a></li>
            </c:if>
        </ul>
```

This is a simple pagination with bootstrap. I don't want the current page to be a link and also make it bold. But as a result current page number turns to be "out of list" as it's seen on image below. Why?

[image link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ycOSy.jpg)

Generated source code:

```
<ul class = "pagination">
    <li><a href="getEmployeesByPage?page=1">Previous</a></li>
    <li><a href="getEmployeesByPage?page=0">1</a></li>
    <li><a href="getEmployeesByPage?page=1">2</a></li>
    <li><b>3</b></li>
    <li><a href="getEmployeesByPage?page=3">4</a></li>
    <li><a href="getEmployeesByPage?page=3">Next</a></li>    
</ul>
```

Comment: Can you share the generated output source code?

Comment: @Wavemaster, sure. Updated.

Comment: @Wavemaster, noticed, that if i remove class = "pagination" it works fine. strange...

Comment: Can you also share the CSS style for `.pagination`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to change

```
<li><b>${i+1}</b></li>
```

to

```
<li class="active"><a href="#">${i+1}</a></li>
```

Don't delete the `class="pagination"` in your `ul`.

Take a look at the [pagination page of bootstrap](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/pagination/) and make sure, your generated code looks like the code in the examples.

Does this work?

Comment: i tried to add class="active" in <li> tag but it didn't work, so i used simlpe pager class. now the current page is in the "right place", but it's just a plain number

Comment: like that: <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">